# trouble with state monad composition

Tags: haskell, state, monads, composition

I was trying out the example given at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad#Complete_and_Concrete_Example_1

How this makes the solution composible is beyond my understanding. Here is what I tried but I get compile errors as follows:

```
Couldn't match expected type `GameValue -> StateT GameState Data.Functor.Identity.Identity b0'
            with actual type `State GameState GameValue'
In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `g2'
In the expression: g1 >>= g2
In an equation for `g3': g3 = g1 >>= g2
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Here is the code: See the end lines

```
module StateGame where
import Control.Monad.State

type GameValue = Int
type GameState = (Bool, Int)

-- suppose I want to play one game after the other
g1 = playGame "abcaaacbbcabbab"
g2 = playGame "abcaaacbbcabb"
g3 = g1 >>= g2

m2 = print $ evalState g3 startState

playGame :: String -> State GameState GameValue
playGame []     = do
    (_, score) <- get
    return score

playGame (x:xs) = do
    (on, score) <- get
    case x of
         'a' | on -> put (on, score + 1)
         'b' | on -> put (on, score - 1)
         'c'      -> put (not on, score)
         _        -> put (on, score)
    playGame xs

startState = (False, 0)

main str = print $ evalState (playGame str) startState
```

Comment: I'd suggest writing explicit type signatures for at least the top-level functions, and maybe also any other terms whose type you're not sure of.  It helps to localize errors, and understand how the type system works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can combine your two games.  The first option is to run the second game after the first game, starting from a fresh state.  You do this using:

```
main = do
    print $ evalState g1 startState
    print $ evalState g2 startState
```

Alternatively, you can have the second game pick up where the first game ended.  You do this using:

```
g3 = do
    g1
    g2
```

... which is just syntactic sugar for:

```
g3 = g1 >> g2
```

... and run it with:

```
main = print $ evalState g3 startState
```

Comment: Thanks. can you give an example of the composition for which ">>=" is needed? Also, what is this type of g3? 
g3 :: StateT GameState Data.Functor.Identity.Identity GameValue

Comment: @user1308560 Yes: main = getLine >>= putStrLn.  This is the desugared version of main = do { x <- getLine; putStrLn x }.  I recommend reading: [You could have invented monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html).

Comment: @user1308560 Also, StateT Identity is the same as State.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry for not being more specific but I want an example of ">>=" in case of the State monad not the IO. Also, if StateT Identity is same as State what about all the gibberish "StateT GameState Data.Functor.Identity.Identity GameValue"?

Comment: @user1308560 Feel free to ask question!  I don't mind at all!  The example for just `State` would be: `get >>= put :: State s ()`, which in `do` notation woud be: `do { x <- get; put x }`.  Every time you use `do` notation it desugars to `(>>=)` under the hood.  For example, in your `playGame` function when you wrote `do { (_, score) <- get; return score }`, it got tranformed to: `get >>= \(_, score) -> return score`.  I'll answer your second question in a second comment.

Comment: @user1308560 Most of the gibberish is just module qualifiers.  When `ghc` gives a type signature that has a type that is not currently in scope, it qualified the type with the module name, so the type `Data.Functor.Identity.Identity` was really just the type `Identity` qualified with its module, which was `Data.Functor.Identity`.  So if you strip the module qualifications, the type you are getting is actually just: `StateT GameState Identity GameValue`, and that is equivalent to `State GameState GameValue`.  To see why, check out the definition for `State` in `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy`.

Answer (score 2):

```
g1 = playGame "abcaaacbbcabbab"
g2 = playGame "abcaaacbbcabb"
g3 = g1 >>= g2
```

`g1` and `g2` are both of type `State GameState GameValue`. But `(>>=)` has type

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

thus its second argument must be a function. If the first argument is `g1`, the function must have the type

```
GameValue -> State GameState b
```

That's the "expected type" from the error message. But `g2` has a different type, that's the "actual type".

The combinator that you want in the definition of `g3` is `(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`,

```
g3 = g1 >> g2
```